# Where do these strange contacts come from?

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account

I recently noticed that in my phone contact list (which is synchronized to the Gmail contacts) there are many contacts that I don't remember adding and that I don't even know.

Has anyone else experienced this? Do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: setting the contacts display option to show only contacts with phone numbers helped me a lot in my case. You may try that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is often caused by linking other social networks (via the appropriate App) or third party E-Mail providers to the Android device. This will cause the contact lists or address books to be synced and shown in your device.

This includes for example

- Last FM
- Yahoo Mail
- Skype
- etc.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the source mentioned by Flow, since Gmail may, depending on your settings, automatically add people you send messages to to your Other Contacts list, that might also be a source of unexplainable contacts in your contact list.

Comment: you are right, I actually encountered many such GMail "one-time" contacts, but I think that's understandable. What I was curious about was why I ended up with some contacts I really knew nothing about.